# Windows Script for automatic date/time correction

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I want a script for windows which keep checking internet every 10 min for current date/time and if system date/time is different, it sets it accordingly with administrator privileges.

Comment: That's a bad idea. Computers check their time with their domain controllers. Security depends on a domain agreeing on the time.

Comment: Open a Windows [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `net time /?` and read the output help how to use `net time` with `/set` and a computer name or domain name to synchronize the time of the machine with the time of another computer or domain controller on running this command with local administrator privileges.

Comment: Run in a command prompt window `w32tm /?` and read the output help how to use Windows Time Service (if enabled at all as by default) with `/resync` to resynchronize time of local machine with time of the configured NTP server or domain controller on being executed with local administrator privileges. `w32tm` can be also used to configure Windows Time Service and change for example the synchronization interval. Documentations about `w32tm` and __Windows Time Service__ can be easily found in world wide web.

Comment: Besides the fact that using such a script is not the optimal solution for synchronising the system date/time, this site is the wrong place for your request. This is a place to ask programming-related **questions** (which your post is clearly not). Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: i know right, due to some reasons, my laptop time keeps changing to previous dates, tried changing cmos battery, ran a full scan for possible viruses/services/programs, the only answer i was looking for, an easy solution through scripts maybe for my problem, before going to local vendor... But i think this forum really is not meant for me.. Thanks (y)

Answer (score 3):

Windows updates the system clock via NTP anyway, with a default frequency of one week. If you want to change the frequency I think you can do something like:

```bsh
Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpClient\ -Name SpecialPollInterval -Value 600
```

where the value is your preferred frequency in seconds.